# Efficiently dropping current changes already saved

Tags: git, commit, magit

I'm beginning with Git and Magit so I don't know to which one my question is specific.

Sometimes I save changes to a file but then don't want to commit them: I simply want to go back to the last commit.

I'm trying to do this from Emacs / Magit and what I do is just insane:

1. I stash the changes (otherwise Magit complains about uncommited/unstashed changes)
2. I checkout a commit *older than the last one* (if I simply try the last one Emacs / magit just leaves my changes there: it doesn't modify the file)
3. I drop the stash
4. I checkout the last commit

This requires lots of keypresses and is absolutely mad.

I'm surely missing something totally obvious but simply can't find what: so I do efficiently drop from Emacs / Magit the last saved changes and simply go back to the last commit?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with `Emacs / Magit`, but I can tell you the equivalent git commands you could run from your shell.

If I understood your question correctly, I believe you're looking for a simple way to revert all changed files in your current working tree. If that not be the case, do not follow these steps ;)

- If you just wish to discard local changes in your working tree for a file without touching the index, you could do this:

  ```
  git checkout -- <FILE>
  ```
- If you want to discard **all** local changes without touching the index, you could run this from the root of your repo:

  ```
  git checkout -- .
  ```
- If you wish to discard all changes in the index as well as the working tree, and want to move your working tree and the index to the state just after a checkout, you can use the `git reset --hard` command. (**Be aware any uncommitted changes in your working tree and even uncommitted changes in your index/staging area will be lost**).

  ```
  git reset --hard HEAD
  ```

  The `HEAD` in the above command is optional BTW.

Comment: You could also go `git checkout -- file` to just get back that file.

Comment: @vonbrand - I already had it as the first item in the list, just didn't word it clearly ;)

Comment: Is there some way to be able to run this from within magit mode? That's what the question is asking, not how to shell out.

Answer (score 1):

in magit `k` is to drop things, so if you want to drop a change, you just have to go on the change you want to revert, and use `k` on it.

You could also use `X` to revert every change in your working tree (beware, no undo for this)